# How do i inject node ENV values into Testcafe Studio test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are using TestCafe Studio to generate tests from the UI.
One area we are struggling is in injecting commandline/node env values into these tests. Is there a way I can inject UserName and Password into TestCafe Studio tests?

I know we can do this in manually written TestCafe JS tests but I can't find any such feature in TestCafe Studio. Any example would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to inject these username and password into basic auth as well as html form based page.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the user name and password into a file:

```json
{
  "userName": "user_1",
  "password": "qwerty"
}
```

Then, use the [Run TestCafe Script](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401265/test-actions/custom-scripts#run-testcafe-script) action to read them from it and log in:
[image]

If you need to log in before each test, put this action into [Before Each hook](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401074/test-directory-structure/hooks) in your fixture.

Comment: Is there no way to do this via command line params? Also, for basic auth is it possible to do this?

Comment: In TestCafe Studio, you can access the environment variables in the "Run TestCafe Script" action in the same way as in the Node.js code. You can use the [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) object. However, if you want to access the command line parameters in a test, you need to use the open-source [TestCafe CLI test runner](https://testcafe.io/).